# Any statistics on whether a fiddle repro helps getting questions answered?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

I often advise people who ask JavaScript questions to provide a reproduction of the problem on JSFiddle or plunkr (or via the new code snippet function, which I haven't used yet).  Are there statistics on how much faster questions get answered that provide a repro case vs. just posting code in the question?

Comment: Maybe some [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/185667) database queries could be used as starting point, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106/185667).

Comment: When i answer questions, i almost never click through to the fiddle. If i can't answer it without going to the fiddle, there isn't enough information in the question (and it isn't worth answering.)